# Hello, Im new to JavaScript and I have a question about isNan() function

Tags: javascript

I am looking at an example for isNaN() function and it has provided this code below.
Can someone please explain why 100F is not a number but 0.0314E+2 is a number? I see that both of these numbers are strings and isNaN function should be able to distinguish a number from the string but I simply dont understand why they are different because both strings have numbers along with a letter and what makes the latter so hard to understand is that it has a letter with E+ operator and somehow that is a number?

```
function milliseconds(x) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return 'Not a Number!';
  }
  return x * 1000;
}

console.log(milliseconds('100F'));
// expected output: "Not a Number!"

console.log(milliseconds('0.0314E+2'));
// expected output: 3140
```

Comment: `Number("100F")` -> `NaN` because `F` is not a valid numeric. `Number("0.0314E+2")` -> `3.14` in scientific notation.

Comment: Scientific notation

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-math-e-function/

Comment: here they explain well with your example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: "Because coercion inside the isNaN function can be [surprising](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior), you may alternatively want to use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)." ([citation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'E' in the string is an abbreviation of 'Exponent'.

In this case, it represents a power of 10.

'E+2' means we multiply the first part of the number by 10^2 = 100.

so '0.0314E+2' means 0.0314 x 100 = 3.14

If the sign were negative, for example, '0.0314E-2' this represents 0.0314 x 10^(-2) = 0.0314 x 0.01 = 0.000314.

This notation allows you to write very large or very small numbers. It is known as Scientific Notation.

However, it can cause issues for checking inputs when you only want numbers because the letter 'E' is often allowed, even if you don't want it, because of this notation.

Comment: Thank you so much that cleared it up for me! This is a refresher of scientific notation for me; its been awhile for me since covering this type of math let alone using it in code, Much appreciated & many thanks!!